# How to determine if association changed in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

ActiveRecord offers change tracking, where calling `#name_changed?` returns true/false depending on whether the `name` attribute changed between when the model was loaded and now.

Is there an equivalent for associations? I am specifically looking for has_many associations, but all association types would be useful.

Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.5.1

Comment: I suppose it would depend on whether Rails caches associations when you query them for an object

Comment: I may be not understanding the question correctly, but shouldn't calling `#name_changed?` on the association work as well?

Comment: @user2490003, I don't want to know if the name of an attribute in one of the records changed, I want to know if any records were added or removed from the association.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not a answer but this is a workaround I came up with.

In my project I was already using the gem [`audited`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) to keep track of changes on the model I also want to receive changes on. In my case the model is `Location` and the model I want to check if the location was changes is `Employee`

In the `after_save` I then check if there is made an audit on the location and if it's created within seconds. If so, I'm able to check the changes.

Simplified example:

```
# app/models/location.rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  audited
end

# app/models/employee.rb
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :inform_about_changes!
  belongs_to :location

  def inform_about_changes!
    last_location_change = location.audits.last
    if last_location_change.created_at.between?(2.seconds.ago, Time.now)
      if last_location_change.audited_changes.include? 'city'
        city_was = last_location_change.audited_changes[0]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Once again, this is not an answer, but it did the job in my case

Answer (score 0):

there is no `#association_changed?` equivalent on associations as far as the documention shows.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html

Answer (score 0):

has_many - nope
but if we talk about `belongs_to :user`
you can use something like this `object.saved_change_to_user_id?`

Comment: `object.saved_change_to_user_id?` == `object.user_id_changed?`, so it only returns true in case object change user, however, i think this question about tracking whether the user belongs to object is changed or not (such as change user name).